# Error con API de publicación en Google Play Console desde Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, google-play-console

Actualmente trabajo con un proyecto Xamarin Android, dónde al momento de realizar la publicación en consola de desarrollo en google no es posible porque me sale el error "This version of the play developer api is no longer available", entonces desde Visual Studio 2017 no me es posible actualizar las dependencias (Nuget). Adjunto imagen del error que me aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la atención, saludos.

Comment: Hola. Compartenos el enlace que indica el problema

Comment: Agrego enlace, que me indica al momento de archivar.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

Comment: Creo que va más allá de lo que menciona el error, prueba subiéndola desde Visual Studio 2019, pudiera parecer un poco improbable pero Visual es muy quisquilloso a veces, también verifica que tengas el Android más reciente (10.0). Recuerda hacer un respaldo de tu proyecto.

link : [visual studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-10)

Comment: @Jorgesys

He estado consulta y es relacionado con el api rest que facilita la consola de google para realizar publicaciones desde otros ambientes diferentes a Android Studio, por lo tanto aun no encuentro detalle de como usar la nueva **versión(v.3)** de publicación del api de desarrolladores de andriod.

Comment: @Luis

He estado consulta y es relacionado con el api rest que facilita la consola de google para realizar publicaciones desde otros ambientes diferentes a Android Studio, por lo tanto aun no encuentro detalle de como usar la nueva **versión(v.3)** de publicación del api de desarrolladores de andriod.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> "This version of the play developer api is no longer available"

indica que una API de la cual haces uso, ya no es soportada, en este caso **la API que estas usando y es obsoleta es específicamente [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/)**

Posiblemente haces uso de una versión que es obsoleta:

> A partir del 1 de diciembre de 2019, las versiones 1 y 2 de la API de
>   desarrollador de Google Play ya no estarán disponibles, por lo que
>   debe actualizar a la versión 3 antes de esta fecha.
>
> Si ve este mensaje, significa que las llamadas a la API de publicación
>   versión 1 o 2 hacen referencia a su aplicación.

Actualiza tu implementación, puedes revisar el ejemplo que comparte Google para la versión 3:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-androidpublisher/v3